# Camera video display oriented incorrectly at launch in iPhone

Tags: iphone, video, camera, orientation, avcapturedevice

I have an iPhone application that works correctly on its own, it properly opens up the camera video feed in the correct orientation (landscape). However, now that I am adding this application to an existing application, when I launch my app inside the integrated application the video feed is not correctly oriented in landscape view. When the iphone is in landscape view, the video feed is in upside down portrait view. However, when I rotate my device and then back to landscape view the camera feed is now correct (landscape). How do I get the video feed to be correctly oriented at launch time?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a storyboard for your camera app, make sure the initial view controller is set to inherit its rotation property.

If not, the issue is almost certainly caused by a logical error in one of these two methods:

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:
- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:

Look at those two methods, both in your camera app and in the larger app you're putting it inside of.

If the issue isn't immediately obvious post the content of those methods here and we can take a look.